# How do you find out if the string is a component of the preceding string

Tags: python, string, list, function

I am trying to write a function that will look at a list of strings and determine if the next string in the list is a sub-string of the preceding string.

So if I had a list of `['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test']`

I will get back `['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Test']`.

I'm not really sure where to even start here.

Comment: why would `"Ryan"` be in the result

Comment: I suggest writing a few small functions for this.  You'll find that this makes things easier.

Comment: yep strictly because there is nothing to compare it to.

Comment: I don't get it.  If a matching substring removes the preceding string you should be left with ['Ry', 'Test']  What am I missing?

Comment: It shouldn't remove the preceding string, only return the strings, in order so Ryan is the first so it stays, Rya is a sub-string of Ryan so it stays and so on Testing isn't a sub-string of Ry so it is ignored but Test is a sub-string of testing so it is returned.

Comment: @ecline6 you would also have 'Rya' because it's part of 'Ryan'.  Regardless, 'Ryan' shouldn't be in the final list if he's describing the problem correctly

Comment: @blandman1990 so you want to keep the first entry in the list no matter what?

Comment: This smells like homework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a list comprehension

```
def find_results(seq): #I'm sure you can name this function better
    return [seq[0]] + [current for previous, current in zip(seq, seq[1:]) 
                       if current in previous]
```

`seq[1:]` is your whole list except the first element

`zip(a, b)` generates pairs of elements for each iterable you pass it.  In this case, the preceeding string, and the current string.

The `in` operator will test if one string is inside of another. `"test" in "testing"` is true

The comprehension says, for each pair of strings (current and previous), construct a list of all the current strings if the current string is a substring of the previous string

Comment: +1 for being named Ryan. Could you change your last name to "Testing"?

Comment: @TimPietzcker lol, if I didn't have to wait a month to change it back

Comment: When I do this I only get the first two, so Ryan and Rya I dont get test

Comment: @blandman1990 it works fine for me.  Are your cases off?  Cause `'test' in 'Testing'` will be false (note the capital 'T')

Comment: you know when someone deletes their comments, and then you just look like you're talking to yourself?  haha.

Comment: LOL afraid of looking crazy?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
def f(lst):
    yield lst[0]

    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        prev_string = lst[i - 1]
        curr_string = lst[i]

        if curr_string in prev_string:
            yield curr_string
```

`f` will be a generator, so to turn it into a list, you pass it to `list`:

```
In [36]: f(['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test'])
Out[36]: <generator object f at 0x02F75F08>

In [37]: list(f(['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test']))
Out[37]: ['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Test']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
l = ['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test'] 
r = []
for i in range(1, len(l)):
  if l[i] in l[i - 1]:
    r.append(l[i])
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
r = [l[i] for i in range(1,len(l)) if l[i] in l[i - 1]]
```

Comment: The list comprehension will cause the first element to be compared to the last element. `l[0-1]`

Comment: Minor nitpick: don't use `l` for variable names. I'd suggest using `L`.

Comment: Worked it some and got it to do what I wanted, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Ryan Haining's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245054/12892), I wrote a generator based version which works with any iterables, not just sequences:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from itertools import izip, tee

def find_results(iterable):
    icur, iprev = tee(iterable)
    yield next(icur)
    for i in (cur for cur, prev in izip(icur, iprev) if cur in prev):
        yield i

print list(find_results(['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test']))
```

The Python 3 version is a bit shorter:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import tee

def find_results(iterable):
    icur, iprev = tee(iterable)
    yield next(icur)
    yield from (cur for cur, prev in zip(icur, iprev) if cur in prev)

print(list(find_results(['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test'])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @CristianCiupitu except I feel the way he has written it is confusing. Here's a simplified version of it.

```
>>> from itertools import izip, tee
>>> def find_results(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    yield next(a)
    for cur, prev in izip(a, b):
        if cur in prev:
            yield cur


>>> print(list(find_results(['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Testing', 'Test'])))
['Ryan', 'Rya', 'Ry', 'Test']
```

Comment: +1 Indeed, the solution for Python 2 might be a bit harder to read because I wanted to show the power of generators.